# How to change button image source in c# on .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, button, maui

I am trying to change the imagesource of a button on the click event of it . I mean when user click the button the imagesource will change . I could change everything like textcolor,backgroundcolor,heights ... except imagesource , I don't even know if it is possible .

this the button

```
<Button x:Name="status" Text="Status 1"   ImageSource="verified.png"  BackgroundColor="#45D991" HeightRequest="38" WidthRequest="110" HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
```

I tried two things, first just simple :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        status.ImageSource = "load.png";
    }
```

second try :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button statusButton = (Button)sender;
        statusButton.ImageSource = "right.png";
       
    }
```

but none of them work the image still the same ,
the last thing i tried : I thought that impossible to change imagesource while it specified in xaml so i remove it and put it in constructor but still the same problem .

Comment: that should work.  Are you sure the image you're trying to load is located in `Resources` and is marked as a `MauiImage`?

Comment: @Jason yes, when i put it in xaml it work fine .

Comment: I would imagine that your ImageSource needs to be assigned from a property in your ViewModel implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, like your other properties.

Comment: detailing @RobertHarvey i think you should use a viewmodel property to reflect the semantic thing (IsValid) instead of the ImageSource. (dont forget INotifyPropertyChanged). and then in your XAML, you use Property Triggers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers#property-triggers) to display the semantic of the VM correctly. that way you do not mix up between the responsibilities of view and view model

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer: It's too bad Maui didn't go the way of Blazor.  In Blazor, this is all about 1/2 of the complexity.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i dont know blazor so good, but yeh, the boilerplating seems to be big in that case. never the less, if you keep the responsibilities separated that way, you can have other controls react to the same viewmodel changes in a different way

Answer (score 2):

In .NET MAUI, you can change the `ImageSource` of a button dynamically by accessing the `Image` property of the button. Here's how you can achieve that:

First, make sure you have the necessary image files (`verified.png`, `load.png`, `right.png`) included in your project. Ensure that the Build Action for these files is set to "EmbeddedResource" or "BundleResource" depending on your platform.

Next, modify your XAML code to remove the `ImageSource` attribute from the button:

```xml
<Button x:Name="status" Text="Status 1" BackgroundColor="#45D991" HeightRequest="38" WidthRequest="110" HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
```

Then, in your code-behind file, you can handle the button click event and update the `ImageSource`:

```cs
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    status.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("load.png");
}
```

Make sure that the image files (`load.png`, `right.png`) are located in the appropriate platform-specific resource folders (e.g., `Resources` for Android, `Resources` for iOS, or `Assets` for UWP).

Alternatively, if you want to use embedded resources, you can change the `ImageSource` assignment to use the `FromResource` method:

```cs
status.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("YourNamespace.load.png", typeof(YourPageType).Assembly);
```

Replace `"YourNamespace"` with the namespace of your project and `YourPageType` with the type of the XAML page where the button is located.

By using either `FromFile` or `FromResource` methods, you should be able to change the `ImageSource` of the button dynamically when the button is clicked.